# PySpark Broadcast join where the left table is smaller to fit in memory than the right table

Tags: join, pyspark, broadcast

What are the options we have when using Join in PySpark and want to use the Broadcast join where my left table is smaller to fit in memory and right is much larger, not fits in memory.

I used the broadcast join when the left table is bigger and the right table is smaller and tried to broadcast the smaller right table. But how to broadcast when the right table does not fit in memory where as left smaller can fit.

Comment: just swap the left/right tables

Comment: My final table is the left table. I need all matches on the left table with the right table.